# Inno Setup: Do not install subfolder if it exists already

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to package everything in `C:\App\Web\*` into an installer.

If the database sub-folder `mysql\data` exists, then I **do not** want to replace these files.

This is my Inno Setup script:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\App\Web\xampp-control.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags:     ignoreversion
Source: "C:\App\Web\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\App\Web\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Excludes: "C:\App\Web\mysql\data\*"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: DirExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\mysql\data\*'))
```

The files in `mysql\data` still get replaced.

I want the installer to avoid overwriting the data folder if the application is already installed (i.e. performing an upgrade).

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your script:

- The first entry `C:\App\Web\*` copies everything unconditionally. The second entry cannot change it.
- The `DirExists` does not support file masks, you can use it to test existence of a directory only. Remove the trailing `\*`

---

This is the correct way:

```
[Files]
...

; Always install everything except the mysql\data
Source: "C:\App\Web\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Excludes: "C:\App\Web\mysql\data\*"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

; Install the mysql\data, only if it does not exist yet
Source: "C:\App\Web\mysql\data\*"; DestDir: "{app}\mysql\data"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; \
    Check: not DirExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\mysql\data'))
```